# Global Unwind Segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, storyboard, unwind-segue

I have a reset notification that can be triggered outside of the app and whatever the user was doing will be exited and return to the main screen because the data has become invalid. Currently, I am having to put unwind segues in every view controller but I just want to programmatically call a global performSegueWithIdentifier whenever this notification happens. There are quite a few view controllers and it is not great to have to duplicate this code everywhere, it will become a maintenance issue as new view controllers are added to the project. Is there a straightforward way of doing this?

Comment: How is your navigation through the app happening? Via a navigation controller? If so, can't you do a popToRootViewController?

Comment: Interesting, yes it is a navigation controller at the base and others are tabviews and page views.

Comment: Sounds like a `self.navigationController.popToRootViewController` could solve your issues then in that case. Give it a try and let me know if it works :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can quickly go to specific view controller without segues. If you have one storyboard, invoke this in your view controller.

```
self.view.window.rootViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
```

or go to not initial view controller by storyboard ID

```
self.view.window.rootViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StoryboardID"];
```

If you have several storyboards in app, you should get specific storyboard firstly.

```
UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
self.view.window.rootViewController = [storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];
```

As comments say, if you have navigation controller container, just switch to root view controller.

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```

Comment: Thanks, so if I instantiate a specific view controller, won't it remain on the stack of controllers? I want to pop everything off before going back to the main controller.  Or will setting the window's rootviewcontroller release all those other controllers?

Comment: Quick response is Yes: all current controllers hierarchy will be cleaned, if you haven't retain cycles inside it. Also you should keep in mind that such view controller will be instantiated in a fresh state.